# SpotsDialog has private access in 'dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog

Tags: android, android-studio

With this line of code:

```
AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
waitingDialog.show();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
SpotsDialog(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, int, boolean, android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)'
```

has private access in `dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog`

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party library, you should check its ReadMe guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Declare this as Global Object:

```
public AlertDialog waitingDialog; // let this be public
```

then use this wherever you want to:

```
waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this, "write_your_string_here. for ex: Loading..");
waitingDialog.show();
```

Try it, Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog= new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(MainActivity.this).build();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog= new 
SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(POSTING.this).build();
alertDialog.setTitle("Uploading Post");
alertDialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
alertDialog.show();
```